# Cruzamento de dados em SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-aws

Boa tarde pessoal!

Tenho um banco de dados que possui um campo criptografado. Mas há um outro banco de dados que possui esse de-para.

Seria:
Banco de dados 1
Tabela 1

[Banco de dados 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeO1b.png)

Banco de dados 2
Tabela 2

[Banco de dados 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcAK0.png)

Precisava fazer um código SQL pra AWS fazer esse cruzamento e trazer as informações preenchidas do banco de dados 2.

Comment: Os exemplos devem ser apresentados em formato de texto e não em imagens

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)